# How do I look into the response API from twitter?

Tags: json, api, express, response

I am using React and Express.js to make a toy project like a simple SNS website.
Normally that I know is the server sends a response to the client after receving a request from the client.
And response data type is JSON and it includes all informations about articles which is gonna be rendered on the viewport. And through Chrome devtools, I can see that JSON at 'Network > choose one of xhr > preview'.
Here is my question, I logged in Twitter and tried to check JSON-type response API of the articles through the same way but I couldn't find it.

1. How could I find it?
2. Is it encrypted like something 'Encrypt json serialized response'-ish?

I want to know that production level like Meta, Twitter. Thanks for reading! :)

What I did:

1. Logged in Twitter by my own account.
2. Opend Chrome Devtools and checked Network tab.
3. I clicked Type column to gather 'xhr'.
4. Lots of response typed xhr were there. I looked in one by one but I couldn't find it.

I just wanted to know the structure of JSON as a response API for about Twitter's articles(aka tweet) for real.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the json payload and response by Chrome DevTool.

Steps

#1 Go `twitter.com` with your account with Chrome

```
twitter.com/your_account_name
```

It will be automatically login by cookie

#2 Open DevTool by pressing "F12"

#3 Select `Network` tab and press `clear` icon

[image]

if not, tweet keep to show `event` message
[image]

#4 Tweet your own message

[image]

#5 Stop `Recoding` icon after send Tweet

[image]

#6 Click `CreateTweet` in the `Name` section

[image]

#7 Click `Header` tab, can see HTTP call URL and `post` message with status

[image]

#8 Click `Payload` tab, can see JSON's format  data with Tweet message

[image]

#9 Click `Response` tab, can see returned JSON data

[image]